# Jekyll: Comments.app widget does not show up on my page

Tags: javascript, html, jekyll, telegram, telegram-bot

I have simple jekyll blog where I would love to add [comments.app](https://comments.app) widget.

Here is the code which I use to add the widget:

```html
<h3>Comments:</h3>
<script async src="https://comments.app/js/widget.js?3"
    data-comments-app-website="{{ site.comments.commentsapp-id }}"
    data-limit="{{ site.comments.limit }}"
    data-color="39C4E8" 
    data-dark="1">
</script>
<noscript>
    Comments not available if Javascript is blocked. This is the only function of
    this website which needs Javascript.
</noscript>
```

the *site.comments.commentsapp-id* is stored in my `_config.yml` and it is placed correctly in rendered result.

But the widget does not show on page. What did I do wrong ?

**Update**: In inspect element option I discovered this:

```html
<iframe id="comments-app-Kh5zcvkB-1" src="https://comments.app/embed/view?website=my-id&amp;page_url=%page/title%2F&amp;origin=https://my-site.com&amp;page_title=y-tittle&amp;limit=5&amp;color=39C4E8&amp;dark=1" scrolling="no" style="overflow: hidden; border: medium none;" width="100%" height="0" frameborder="0">
    <head></head><body>Page url invalid</body>
</iframe>
```

Comment: Do you see Javascript errors in the console? When you view the page source, do you see that the Liquid has compiled, meaning that instead of `{{ site.comments.commentsapp-id }}` you see the comments app id you added to your config file?

Comment: Only thing in console is `Layout was forced before the page was fully loaded. If stylesheets are not yet loaded this may cause a flash of unstyled content.`. Yes, liquid has compiled correctly.

Comment: By *console* I meant the browser console in your developer tools, not the terminal. But looks like you got it, so no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved this problem. It was caused by relative canonical URL in head of document.

So I replaced this:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ page.url }}">
```

with this:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="{{ absolute_url }}">
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: You'll probably want to use `{{ page.url | prepend: absolute_url }}` if this is in a shared layout. Otherwise all your pages will have the same canonical address.